# Trigger background mail for iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, email

I am working on an iOS swift App, where I have to trigger an email in the background with some 6-digit code to the recipient, for reset password. 
I searched and it seems not feasible in iOS. Even the 'SKPSMTPMESSAGE' cannot be used for swift.

Is there any way I can use background email trigger for sending email from iOS swift?

Comment: This isn't clear. Is the email being sent from the user's device? If so, who is it being sent to and who must it appear to be from?

Comment: Yes the email is sent from user's device. Sent to user's email id which the user will input. and the mail should come from, like some id reserved for this process only.

Comment: Why would you send an email from the user's device to the user's device while appearing to come from someone else? What's the point of using email at all in this case? Your requirement is very unclear.

Comment: Email is sent from the app to the email id. Its not just user device to user's device, email can be opened anywhere else too. Lets just say, I want to replicate the welcome greeting message on registration or forgot password problem, similar kinda experience.

Comment: I have used mail gun for this purpose. They have a pretty generous free tier and a simple api

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with Apples `MFMailComposeViewController` which is used to show Mail interface for users to send mail.

What you would have to do is send email via your backend where you would call an API endpoint and server would send the mail. But you cannot do it with Apples frameworks...

Comment: I know we cannot do with the Apple frameworks. I was wondering is there any framework available to do so.. i am aware about sendgrid, mailgun etc. Any idea if any free frameworks?